# Simultaneous queries on the same table / view affect performance

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

If I had a view (or table) which contained millions of rows and I executed these two queries from different sessions, would one query be adversely affected by another? (Please note no DML will be going on)

> **e.g.** Select * from t1 where sex = 'M'; (Returns 20 columns and 10,000 rows)
>   select sex from t1 where rownum < 2;

What about if I had multiple sessions executing query 1? Would they all be equally slow until one of them had been cached (provided it was large enough)?

I am currently experiencing degraded performance when executing similar queries in a load balancing test for the quicker queries, however when executed separately (even when the result hasn't been cached) I am getting 'normal' response times.

Answer (score 0):

If the tables are not being modified and the queries are using base tables, then it would be surprising if these two queries were interfering with each other.  In particular, the second query:

```
select sex
from t1
where rownum < 2;
```

Should simply be fetching one row and going very fast.

The first can take advantage of an index on `t1(sex)`.

If `t1` is really a view, then Oracle probably has to do all the processing for the view.  Twice, once for each query.  If the view is complex, then this would put a load on the server and slow everything down.

Comment: The view is a join on several smaller tables to create a 'master_all_clients' view. The queries which are running slow aren't quite as simple as the example given, however I am seeing timings of >2 secs, when run outside of the load balancing they are taking 0.1-0.2 secs. Is there a way to speed up this process? If I created another view e.g. 'view_for_slow_sql' (20 columns) and another for 'view_for_quick_sql' (2 columns), both referencing the same underlying tables - would this help at all, or does it still require the same shared block reads on the tables?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at what is happening in the buffer cache, in particular V$DB_CACHE_ADVICE for buffer hit/miss ration? Are there any candidates (in the underlying tables) for adding to the "KEEP" buffer to avoid IO? To be fair it can take a while to monitor this and understand what the picture is before deciding what action to take, but it is worth looking at. More information here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGDBA/tune_buffer_cache.htm#TGDBA555 .

Comment: I believe this data is cached every 12 hours into memory, however it is this 'initial' caching I think which is causing the load balance to time out for the other queries, however I'm not 100% certain if this is the cause or not, or if it's realistically possible that this would be the reason why.

Comment: So, if you flush the buffer prior to running the other query, does it make any difference?

Comment: How do I go about flushing the buffer? I have tried to do this in the past and it pretty much stems from the fact that a. It's very difficult to actually do reliably and b. wouldn't actually be like the live environment anyway due to it being in an artificial state. If I have to cache the results and then run the tests that's fine, for the period twice daily where the results are cached it will have to be an accepted degredation of service, however I need to 'know' this is what was causing the other time outs in my tests, and isn't anything more serious.